# Angular2 - Browser back-button with fragment identifier

Tags: html, angular, browser

Given a link to an anchor with the fragment identifier #bar on the home page:

```
<a href="foo#bar" class="button">link to #bar-anchor in /foo</a>
```

When I click the link the browser redirects me to `/foo#bar` which is what I want. But when I click the back-button in the browser - It brings me back to `/foo` instead of the home page.

I'm not looking for an href to `/` - what I need is a solution that generally brings me back to where I came from after a redirect to an anchor/fragment on another page.

Comment: can u clarify it more?

Comment: @user32 - in general - you click an anchor-link on index.html and jump to the place of the anchor inside foo.html. so far, so good. but when you try to go back to index.html through the back-button of the browser - instead of rendering index.html the browser only jumps to the top of foo.html. if you click the back-button a second time you go back to index.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if it has been a problem with the angular version I've used. On the final version 2 the problem disappears.